# Spring Boot Security Basic auth access denied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make an authenticated GET request on one of the resources:

```
http://user:psw@localhost:8090/devices
```

This works fine from the browser. But from National Instrument GWeb I keep getting Code 401 (Unauthorized).

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private final DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService;
    
    public SecurityConfiguration(DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService) {
        super();
        this.databaseUserDetailsService = databaseUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
    }
      
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(this.databaseUserDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }
      
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://rog-valerio", "http://localhost:8090"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

From the configure() method:

```
httpSecurity.cors().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
```

I'm I am not wrong this should mean that any request should be able to authenticate.
By enabling spring security debug, when I try to make the authenticated request I get the following:

```
2022-03-09 10:37:00.520 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /devices
2022-03-09 10:37:00.520 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.521 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.521 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /devices] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-03-09 10:37:00.522 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8090/devices to session
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@30dfc62d
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-03-09 10:37:00.523 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2022-03-09 10:37:00.524 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.524 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-03-09 10:37:00.524 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2022-03-09 10:37:00.525 DEBUG 27408 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator : filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=05282221D24CA222616679CE3049C092], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

And access is denied. Username and password are correct. Why am I getting the request rejected? Maybe there is some configuration that I am missing?

Comment: remove `cors()` from `httpSecurity` and try, possibly cors issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, configuration was fine. But, as stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#examples , I added "Authorization" header with base64 encoded username and password. Now it works.

I'll not delete the question because maybe it'll be useful to somebody